# 75 Ohm Coaxial Cable Used On a 600 Ohm Output

Tags: audio, frequency, impedance, cables, shielding

I'm working on restoring an HP 211A square-wave generator and I'm looking to add a shielded cable to the 600 ohm output. I've got some spare 75 ohm RG59 cabling and I was wanting to know if using that would have any detrimental effects on the output such as signal loss due to the impedance mismatching. The length of cable will be 10" - 12", the output will be between 1Hz and 1MHz and mostly used on loads like oscilloscopes and maybe stereo receivers.

To clarify, the RG59 cabling would run from the V10 and V11 plates to the wiper on R71, and then another cable from the non-grounded pin of R71 to the output screw post. I'd likely use 75 ohm cabling to run to any devices on the output though anyways.

Thank you.

[image: 600 Ohm Output On The Circuit In Question]

Comment: What about the 75 Ohm output in the upper right corner?

Comment: That's a separate output that uses a much lower voltage than the 600 ohm output. The 600 ohm output is 55Vp and the 75 ohm output is 5Vp or so. Both are adjustable though.

Comment: Yes, about what you'd expect if you hooked up the 75 Ohm cable to the 600 Ohm output (discounting reflection questions.) If you want to drive 75 Ohms at 55 Vp, you'll need a driver capable of 20 W. Yes?

Comment: Thank you for responding and letting me know that the 75 ohm cabling should work fine. I've not worked much with impedance matching and the like so I appreciate it.

Comment: I can't say that the circuit won't distort when loaded down like that. Apparently, that's a 2 - 2.5 watt output and you will be loading it down pretty heavy.

Comment: The original cable used was a standard piece of 22 or 24AWG wire. Would I be better off using something like that like how it came from the factory?

I double-checked the manual and it says that the 75 ohm output will have 3.5Vp across a 75 ohm load and 7Vp open. The 600 ohm output will have 27Vp across a 600 ohm load and 55Vp open. I hope that helps.

Comment: So it's designed to deliver 600 mW into a 600 Ohm load. Pretty light-weight. I don't think those plate loads will do well into 75 Ohm. You may need to adjust what's driving the grids, too, to get a better operating point.

Comment: @jonk what are "plate loads"?

Comment: @P2000 Those 1200 Ohm pots? Those.

Comment: @jonk Understood. I think what I'll do is use some phono cable that's closer to the original cable cross-section but still shielded. I may need to experiment with what gives me the best output. I find it odd that the 75 ohm output is shielded but not the 600 ohm.

I'll finish fixing up the unit and then look into the grids. It's going to the used in calibration and testing environments so the output power matters less to me than a clean output. Thank you for your input; you've been great.

Comment: FWIW the wavelength of 1MHz is 300m

Comment: Why not use twin-lead cable?  Standard TV stuff is 300 ohm, but that should be close enough.

Comment: User "Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75" pointed out this same thing. I might end up using some 300 ohm flat antenna cabling. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

If I searched right, the unit has a maximum output frequency of 1MHz. A 1MHz wave has 300m wavelength in free space. It will be slightly longer in a cable. So the cable you will use, will be electrically short for sure, and only the capacitive loading of the cable and thus the bandwidth is to be assessed. Such a coaxial cable should have roughly 100pF/m capacitance. 600Ω output resistance and 100pF forms a pole at 2.67MHz, so you are good* up to 1m cable length for the full range of the instrument. If you want a 1MHz frequency with a waveform including harmonics, then you should reduce your cable length, or the output impedance before the cable.

*Only 6% amplitude loss for a 1MHz sinusoid signal

Comment: He said his cable length would be around 10-12" (up to 4m). I don't think it should be a problem but it's longer than the 1m limit you mentioned.

Comment: @Camion. That's true. I've used 1m, because it is a nice unit for cable lengths. I think the poster could divide or multiply by 2.5 easily. I also deliberately used a different unit to make him rethink whether he really needs that 2.5-3m cable length, because it could limit the performance of his setup. Often questioning the assumptions might lead to an idea for a better solution.

Comment: I read 10-12" as inches hence up to 30cm.  For feet, I would expect 10-12'.

Comment: @badjohn that's another reason why I stick to 'm'. :) As a European, I sometimes misinterpret these imperial units.

Comment: @HorrorVacui I am familiar with feet and inches as I live in the UK but that doesn't mean that I like them.  I would like to see them disappear entirely but that seems very unlikely.  However, they certainly should be avoided in an international context.

Comment: ooops yes, sorry, you're right. my bad.

Answer (score 4):

At the frequencies your using there is little effect in using a lower impedance cable. However you will want to terminate it with a 600 ohm load so the source can still drive it at full voltage.

Frequencies at or above 50MHZ are very fussy about impedance matching and standing waves and you are nowhere near that high in frequency.

600 ohms is typical for audio < 0.01HZ up to 1MHZ. That is the range of my 600 ohm analog audio generator. 1MHZ to 10MHZ for ultra-sound is common today, so 10MHZ is nothing special anymore.

You *do* want to avoid cable with an impedance above 600 ohms, as this could deform the edges of frequencies approaching 1MHZ (for square waves).

Cables lower than 75 ohm become a "bulk" problem as the center conductor can be thick, making the cable tough to bend. Avoid 50 ohm and 25 ohm cables for this reason, and their higher cost.

For a "cleaner" square wave at 1MHZ you can load the end-point with less than 600 ohms, by going down a 100 ohms at a step, but the signal amplitude will drop. You have to decide if signal amplitude is more important than signal quality.

Comment: "50MHZ are very fussy about impedance matching and standing waves" I take it you are dismissing these effects sub 50MHz because of the typical cable length for lab equipment, or is there a different reason?

Comment: @P2000 Yes the effects begin before 50MHZ and get worse at higher frequencies. There was no need for a graph to plot out increasing errors with frequency and rise/fall times

Comment: @Sparky256 I think what I'll do is try some shielded phono cabling since I have lots. That should be closer to the factory cable impedance while still providing a shield. Shunting a 600 ohm resistor to ground is a good idea and I'll keep those other points in mind. Thank you.

Comment: In this frequency range, the signal will not behave as wave, since the wavelength will around 450m for 1MHz. Assuming cable lengths of 2.5m, it is still not an issue. Also I've used many 50Ohm cable which were very flexible and lightweight. Z0 of a coax depends on the ratio of outer and inner diameter, therefore they does not need to have a strong inner conductor.

Answer (score 3):

RG59 Coax is 75  Ohms and as I recall 30pF/ft.
Twisted pair impedance and pF/ft depend on twists /ft.
The fewer twists, the higher the impedance and inductance must be considered as well.

It becomes a matter of tradeoffs whether you have rounded edges or ringing or attenuation with properly matched RC impedance divider like an 8:1 to 75 Ohms or unshielded wire prone to magnetic pickup or lightly shielded twisted pair with large twists.

- degree of squareness at 1MHz
- length of twisted pair overall
- the impedance of load

Comment: After reading your response I think that testing different cabling on the output to find the results I like best is in order. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Keep in mind long scope probe grounds are inductive and will cause apparent ringing .

Comment: Yes, thank you. I always try to keep my ground wires as short as I can. I think I'm going to try some shielded phono cables as they'll be close to the original wire's cross section.

Comment: \$Z=\sqrt {\dfrac {L}{C}}\$  where L is ~fixed  ~5nH/cm but C ~<1pF/cm depends on insulation gap 1/x of paired wires. Remember flat TV Antenna wire ? that gap is 300 Ohms, old phono Coax will be more than 100 Ohms and more likely 75.  Twisted pair 8~12 twist/ft is 100~250 ohms depending on wire gap.. But then you can replace whole box with a single CMOS IC with variable f 18V 10 Hz to 1MHz square wave if you wanted.

Comment: nice vintage antique.

Comment: Using your -18V supply and 18V rated CMOS '14 http://tinyurl.com/y7qv7ccy

Comment: I like the older equipment and they're fun to work on so I'm really wanting to get the best out of this that I can, since it will do everything that I need it to. It'll be used for calibrations and a little audio generation for testing circuits, though I'll likely be using the 75 ohm output for that.

I won't be using a twisted pair due to it being a singular output without differential pairing. I'll see if I can figure out the rough impedance of the original wire to give me a better ballpark to work with, though since it's just 22 or 24 AWG wire I don't think it's anything special.

Comment: OK but AWG 22 or 24 spaced like old flatwire TV cable is 300 Ohms, so just use that.

Comment: I see. I could just trim down the original cable then, as they have it twice as long as it needs to be. It's unshielded, which is a pain.

Comment: One last question. If I use 300 ohm flat antenna wire, would it be advisable to ground the second lead or tie them both to the signal output?

Comment: Yes Grounding one side reduces stray hum crosstalk but increases capacitance 60pF/m . So ground it.

Answer (score 1):

600 ohm is unrealistic; needs center conductor about the size of an atom, shield with diameter of the universe, from what I heard.

Use  the 75 ohm; you are not expecting standing waves, so don't worry.

Regarding achieving 600 ohm COAX is not the same as achieving 600 ohm TWINLEAD. Pole/crossbar mounted telephone cables are twinlead.

Comment: not quite the accurate ratio of diameters for 600 Ohms, but 30pF/1ft Coax is OK = 5kohm @ 1MHz.. but @ 8ft =240pF will attenuate 6dB @ 1MHz and turn a square into a triangle wave

Comment: "The first long telephone air lines (two wires on the poles separated from each other at some distance) used to have impedance of around 600 ohms." https://www.epanorama.net/documents/wiring/twistedpair.html

Comment: A center conductor with a diameter of a human hair and a shield with a diameter of a mile gives a coaxial cable with impedance close to 600 ohms.